# Is there any use of reducing ripple in boost converter greatly below the tolerance level?In what applications is extremely high stability important?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, boost, stability, ripple

suppose i have a circuit which already has low ripple.Will decreasing the ripple by a little more be of any use?If so,in what applications is this useful?Please explain with an example.Thank you!

Comment: tolerance level once defined, lowering the ripple more will improve the performance but the contribution is questionable.

Comment: All your questions can be answered with an answer which starts with "It depends..." You're thinking in terms of "this is always true" and that is not useful. You must describe the actual design and then conclusions can be drawn from that. Then the answer applies to that design. Another design will result in different answers. In this state your question is too vague and unanswerable.

Comment: I mean, **who** defined the tolerance level? Right, that was you, the user of the supply circuitry. If you say "I see no advantage in making ripple better than that", then the answer is **obviously** "there's no advantage".

Comment: Fix the title.  It's for giving someone a quick idea what the question is about, not for asking whole questions.

Comment: I just started reading the body of the question, and it's very sloppy and largely incomprehensible.  *Screw this*.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your boost-switch-reg (BSR) runs at 2MegaHertz with 0.1v ripple, and also produces some parasitic ringing at 100MHz with 0.1v ripple. You have successfully stepped up that battery from 3v to 5v. Are you happy? Are you done?

Suppose that 5 volts (with ripple at 2 and at 100MHz) must be used in a weigh-scale sensor/amplify/quantize task. The OpAmps have no ability to dodge ripple at 2Mhz nor at 100MHz; whatever trash/ripple/spikes enter the VDD pins will appear on the output pins, because the internal circuits cannot move fast enough to prevent that fast energy movement thru the transistors. The system needs 1microVolt quantization. Thus you need to think about reducing the VDD trash/ripple/spikes down to the 1microVolt level.

Linear regulators will not be useful, because linear regulators have substantial parasitic capacitance from Vin_unreg to Vout_reg, thru the power transistor that is huge, to dissipate the heat. You need to build your own trash rejection network, of cascaded RC LPF and LC LPF and LRC LPF; the last, the LRC LPF is the best, because the R lets you control the dampening/ringing, and the L+C uses the rising Z_L and the falling Z_C to achieve two poles of filtering.

As you implement these VDD filters, 
1) do not share vias among capacitors; 1nanoHenry of a via, and 10mA/nanosecond of ringing energy thru that via, produces 10 milliVolts across that via. Thus GND is not quiet.

2) calculate the magnetic coupling between adjacent inductors; it ain't zero

3) calculate the magnetic coupling between adjacent capacitors; its ain't zero

4) the electric field of a SwitchReg, 1cm away from a "quiet VDD of 1uV floor",
will inject trash into your quiet VDD, erasing all your hard work. Assuming the parallel-plate cap model, a 1cm plate area, 1cm spacing, thru air, is 0.1pF.
Assuming 10 voltpp ringing at 100MHz, the slewrate is 3 billion volts per second; the current thru 0.1pF is 3e9 * 1e-13 ==3e-4amp = 0.3 milliAmps, injected into your "quiet VDD".

By the way, the free tool Signal Chain Explorer includes VDD filtering+PSRR and Hfield modeling of magnetic-trash injected into the loop formed by signal trace,
between two stages, and the signal return. You select stages (gain, LPF, etc) on the left margin. You edit the PSRR for each stage and customize the VDD L/R/C. On top right, click "gargoyles" and then edit which interferers you want to remain active. SCE is from robustcircuitdesign.com